# Xamarin wont work on the device but works fine in Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, api, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the following simple HttpWebRequest in my code behind for click event: (VS 2017)

```
        public void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.10/api/c3knn1r79DQY391tANlYD9u9Jlm4U5Ch54lqm2fd/lights/6/state");
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "PUT";
         request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
        valueLabel.Text = "DONE";
    }

     public static void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
        string postData = "{\"on\":true}";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    }

    public static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

And it seems to work in my visualstudio_andriod-23_x86. and it turn the light on. BUT when I deploy that to my Samsung Note 4 device, nothing is happening. NO error or nothing and no lights comes on. I add premission to INTERNET under Android Manifest.  here is the out put log:

[image]

Also, I noticed in the log that:
AOT module 'System.Net.Requests.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/App2.Android-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Net.Requests.dll.so" not found

But I get this Error line in working Emulator. so that is not the issue.
Any ideas any one? Please  help.   Thanks

Comment: What have you done to debug this?  Are you sure your device can connect to that IP?  Have you checked your server logs to see if the request is received?

Comment: yes, I can pings the device (192.168.0.10) from my note 4. This ip address is a Philips Hue bridge device. And I have Hue apps working fine on my note 4 and I can turn lights off and on. So i know it connects just fine with the device.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after spending hours I realized that I had to reset the router. And it is working now